# Select multiple children from within multiple children in a <ul>

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list structure that looks as follows:

```
<ul id="BirdMother" class="parent">
    <ul class="child">
        <li class="baby">
    </ul>
    <ul class="child">
        <li class="baby">
    </ul>
    <ul class="child">
        <li class="baby">
    </ul>
</ul>
```

I want to select all the `baby` list items in an iterative manner to use in a function that looks like this: `function feedBabies(babyList)`.

How can I select all the `baby` items?

**Edit:** What if there are multiple baby items in the page and I only want the babies from a certain parent list. Eg: Only Bird babies. (Edited the code above).

Comment: Reasonably certain the only allowable child of a `<ul>` is an `<li>` element. but to get your elements you should do something like `babies = $('#useThisList .child .baby');`

Comment: Try $('.baby').text('babies');

Comment: `$('#useThisList .baby')`

Comment: This is just a selector question, not really jQuery specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use class selector

```
var babyList = $(".baby");

feedBabies(babyList);
```

For certain parent

```
var babyList = $("#BirdMother .baby");

feedBabies(babyList);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you have solution

```
$("#useThisList > ul").each(function(){
alert($(this).html());//this will give you html 
alert($(this).text());// this will give you text in li
});
```